# Is it possible to change a job ID to something human-readable?

Tags: pbs, supercomputers

I'd like to send myself a text when a job is finished. I understand how to change the job name so that the .o and .e files have the appropriate name. But I'm not sure if there's a way to change the job ID from a string of numbers to a specified key so I know which job it is. I usually have a lot of different jobs going at once, so it's difficult to remember all the different job ID numbers. Is there a way in the .pbs script to change the job ID so that when I get the message I can see which job it is rather than just a string of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Torque and add the [-N flag](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/4-0-2/Content/topics/commands/qsub.htm#-N), then you can add a name to the job. It will still use the numeric portion of the job id as part of the output and error filenames, but this allows you to add something to help you distinguish among your jobs. For example:

`$ echo ls | qsub -N whatevernameyouplease`